# Does anyone know why I get an unresponsive pygame window when running this code

Tags: python, pygame

```
def run_game():
    """Initialise the game and create a screen object."""
    pygame.init() 
    ai_settings = Settings()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,ai_settings.screen_height)) 

    ship = Ship(screen)

    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():  
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

    #Redraw the screen for each pass through the loop. ie fill the screen with colour.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_colour) 

    #Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip() 
    # Will update the screen as game elements move around. Making the game look smooth.


    ship.blitme() # added after background so appears ontop of it.


run_game()
```

Comment: You will never reach anything past the `sys.exit()` line due to the `while True:` block. The only way it ever exits the while loop is by quitting the game.

Comment: Check your indentation. You have not placed some of your lines in `while` loop.

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/PygameIntro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation is off, or atleast the only apparent issue. I tried running and on line 5 setting is not defined. There are other classes not defined in what you gave. Here it is with correct indentation. (had to switch `pygame.display.flip()` and `ship.blitme()`)

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    #Redraw the screen for each pass through the loop. ie fill the screen with colour.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_colour) 
    ship.blitme() # added after background so appears ontop of it.
    #Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip() 
    # Will update the screen as game elements move around. Making the game look smooth.
```